# Rails TDD with RSpec & Capybara fail to pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, tdd, capybara, rspec-rails

I'm quite new to Rails TDD but would like to take this chance to learn it up. However, I have a MVC app which receives customer's feedback. What i did was to developed the function first and started TDD later on ( Which i know it should be the other way round :P. But because i'm new to TDD, so i thought i would put them once i have my functionality done ( route , controller, model validation ).

However, i couldn't get my test to pass. Can i know what is wrong with the test code ? And how should i create a SAMPLE data ONCE and use it to test for all the context in 1 controller.  How should i organize my test. Any tips what can be done to improve for a beginner in TDD ? I;ve read some blogs & articles whereby we can use factorygirl ? But how should i define the "data" and do i need extra file to store the values or something ?

Also correct me if i'm wrong. Is Capybara used for UI test ? As in it's used more on UI test. Other tools like Selenium can be use to substitute Capybara right ?

**feedback.rb**

```
class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name, :message => "Name is required before giving a feedback."
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i, :message => "Invalid email address !", :allow_blank => true
  validates :telephone_no, :numericality => {:allow_blank => true}
end
```

**feedbacks_controller.rb**

```
class FeedbacksController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @feedback = Feedback.create(feedback_params)

    if @feedback.errors.any?
      flash[:error] = @feedback.errors
      render 'new'
    else
      redirect_to :back
    end

  end

  def new
    @feedback = Feedback.new
  end

  private
    def feedback_params
      params.require(:feedback).permit(:name, :email, :telephone_no, :comment,
                     :approved)
    end

end
```

**feedback_controller_spec.rb**
    require "rails_helper"

```
describe 'Feedback#Create' do

  context 'when param[:name] is not present' do
    @feedback = Feedback.create
    it 'should flash error' do
      expect(flash[:error]).to match(/Name is required before giving a feedback .*/)
    end
    it 'should render back to new' do
      is_expected.to render_template new_path
    end
  end


  context 'when param[:name] is present' do
    @feedback = Feedback.create(:name => "Hah")
    @feedback.save
    it 'should redirect to homepage' do
      is_expected.to redirect_to new_feedback_path
    end
  end


  context 'when param[:name] is present but with invalid param[:email]' do
    it 'should flash error' do
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats a lot of questions in one question, and will probably be flagged for being overly broad - but here's a basic overview

Capybara: a library for controlling browsers and making assertions based on the content of the pages in those browsers.  If you use the selenium driver then Capybara would be using seleniun, so yes you could swap out Selenium for Capybara and write a bunch more code - Capybara just makes it easier.  Capybara is used for feature specs (end to end tests driven through the UI) - not controller specs, and none of your tests shown are currently using Capybara.  Its matchers can also be used in view specs.

Data for tests: Data should be created for each test so that every test is independent of every other test.  RSpec, by default, runs the tests in random order in order to enforce that.  There are two main ways of creating the data for the tests in rails, fixtures and factories.  FactoryGirl is one implementation of factories and allows you to set the default values for attributes in a model and then override those values with only the attribute values specifically needed for the test (While using the other default values to keep the objects valid).  The [Getting Started Guide](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md) gives lots of examples on using it.